# Keil uVision 5.23.0.0 compilation error(s) C4065E

Tags: embedded, keil

I have a project in `Keil uVision version 5.23.0.0` for [STM32F103RC microcontroller](http://www.st.com/en/microcontrollers/stm32f103rc.html) and my project is located under `C:\Projects\TestProj\LCDController\` on NTFS file system using `Windows 7 x64 Ultimate` as `Virtual Machine` in `VMWare Player`. Now, when I try to build project, I get following errors:

```
*** Using Compiler 'V5.06 update 4 (build 422)', folder: 'C:\Keil_v5\ARM\ARMCC\Bin'
Rebuild target 'LcdController'
creating preprocessor file for gpio.c...
compiling gpio.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for main.c...
compiling main.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for i2c.c...
compiling i2c.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_it.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_it.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for spi.c...
compiling spi.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal_msp.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal_msp.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for lcd_dogm128_6.c...
compiling lcd_dogm128_6.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for lcd_dogm128_6_alphabet.c...
compiling lcd_dogm128_6_alphabet.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for lcd_srf06eb.c...
compiling lcd_srf06eb.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for system_stm32f1xx.c...
compiling system_stm32f1xx.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal_flash.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal_flash.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal_spi_ex.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal_spi_ex.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal_rcc.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal_rcc.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal_tim.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal_tim.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal_cortex.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal_cortex.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal_gpio.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal_gpio.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal_spi.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal_spi.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal_gpio_ex.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal_gpio_ex.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal_i2c.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal_i2c.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal_rcc_ex.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal_rcc_ex.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal_tim_ex.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal_tim_ex.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal_pwr.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal_pwr.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal_dma.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal_dma.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
creating preprocessor file for stm32f1xx_hal_flash_ex.c...
compiling stm32f1xx_hal_flash_ex.c...
Error: C4065E: type of input file '..\Inc' unknown
assembling startup_stm32f103xe.s...
linking...
.\LcdController\LcdController.axf: error: L6002U: Could not open file .\lcdcontroller\gpio.o: No such file or directory
Finished: 0 information, 0 warning, 0 error and 1 fatal error messages.
".\LcdController\LcdController.axf" - 1 Error(s), 0 Warning(s).
Target not created.
Build Time Elapsed:  00:00:04

Batch-Build summary: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped - Time Elapsed: 00:00:04
```

The error is related (I think) to `Project Include paths`:
[image: Keil Include Settings]
Why I am getting these errors and how do I solve them? Now, according to @LP's comment, this is the procedure for setting up **Include dirs**:
**STEP 1 - Adding Inc directory**
I am selecting `Inc` directory through `Keil GUI`:[image: GUI Selection]
and when I select `C:\Projects\TestProj\LCDController\Inc` directory, my directory path gets truncated into `..\Inc.`:[image: GUI Selection 1][image: GUI Selection 2]. Is maybe bug in `Keil` and the path is wrong? Same happens for other two include dirs.

Comment: Is `Inc` directory at `C:\Projects\TestProj\Inc` ? Same for the others in inlcude paths

Comment: @LP The `Inc` is located in `C:\Projects\UltraSound\LCDController\Inc`, extending question.

Comment: So I think `..` is not correct. `..` means _one level up_. You should use `./Inc`.

Comment: This is not include path error. If so, you would get "No such file/folder" error.

Comment: @LPs If I change `..` to `.` same errors persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it will be the case but this sometimes works.

1. close project
2. close Keil
3. reopen  project

this is because Keil have many internals errors.